# Image size mismatch in postgres 9.1

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am using postgres PostgreSQL 9.1 and having a table with column bytea data type. When tried to insert an image, it is able to insert the image into the table, the schema of the table is as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE emp
(
  uname character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  pass character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  dob date,
  country character varying(20),
  region character varying(20),
  description character varying(3000),
  role character varying(100),
  photo bytea,
  CONSTRAINT emp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uname )
 )
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
 );
ALTER TABLE emp
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The sample java code is as follows:

```
package com.q4;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.*;

public class DataTest {
   public void insert() throws Exception
   {
       Connection c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\pics\\viticcio.jpg");
        int counter = 0;


       String sql ="insert into emp(uname, pass,name,photo) values (?,?,?,?)";
       PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
       pstmt.setString(1, "Senthil1");
       pstmt.setString(2, "Password");
       pstmt.setString(3, "Senthil1");
        //pstmt.setBlob(4, fis);

       while(fis.read( ) != -1) counter++;
       byte[] b= new byte[counter];
       fis.close();
       fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\pics\\viticcio.jpg");
       for(int i = 0;i<counter;i++)
       {
           b[i] = (byte)fis.read();
          // System.out.print(b[i]);
       }
       System.out.println("Input File Size : " + counter); //Output 1

       System.out.println(counter);
       pstmt.setBytes(4, b);
      // pstmt.setBlob(4, fis, counter);
       pstmt.executeUpdate();
       System.out.println("Successfully insertted ..."); 

   }
   public void select() throws Exception
   {
      String sql = "select * from emp where uname = ?";
      Connection c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
      PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
      pstmt.setString(1, "Senthil1");
      ResultSet set = pstmt.executeQuery();
      if(set.next())
      {
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\test.jpg");


          byte[] a = set.getBytes("photo");
          System.out.println("Output Filesize : "+a.length); //Output 2
          for(int i = 0; i <a.length;i++)
          {
           fos.write((byte)a[i]);   
       //    System.out.print((byte)a[i]);
           fos.flush();
         }
           fos.close();
      }
      pstmt.close();
      c.close();
  }
  public static void main(String[]s) throws Exception
  {
       new DataTest().insert();
       new DataTest().select();
   }
}
```

The output I am getting when run this program is given below, and the file test.jpg gets created in C:\ but the size of this file is twice as the size of the file read.

```
   Input File Size : 6455
6455
Successfully insertted ...
SELECT ......... 12909
```

Please clarify What could be the root cause of the problem.
Thanks in advance
Senthil

Answer (score 1):

1. fis.read() returns the number of bytes read, to get the data initialize the byte array (in my code, this is *b*) to the file length and call the read as follows:

   `File file = new File("C:\\pics\\viticcio.jpg");`

   `byte[] b = new bye[file.length()];`

   `fis.read(b);`

   `pstmt.setBytes(4, b);`
2. [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is read-only by default. To set it updatable initialise as follows:

`PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue is resolved. I am using postgres 9.1 and using the driver for postgres 8.2. When I replaced the driver for postgres 9.1, got the issue resolved.